# Bukkit Custom Inventory spawn eggs

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How do you put a Creeper spawn egg into a custom inventory? Can you continue my lines of code so I understand what you did to do it? For additional information, the creeper spawn egg ID is 383:50.

```
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, "Disguise Menu");

    ItemStack spawnItem = nameItem(Material.MONSTER_EGG, ChatColor.AQUA + "Admin Vanish");

    inv.setItem(4, spawnItem);
    player.openInventory(inv);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your SpawnEgg ItemStack you should do the following:

```
ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(Material.MONSTER_EGG, 1, EntityType.CREEPER.getTypeId());
```

That creates an MonsterEgg for a Creeper.

To rename it:

```
ItemMeta meta = stack.getItemMeta();
meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Creeper Egg");
stack.setItemMeta(meta);
```

To add that to your custom inventory, you can do

```
inv.setItem(4, stack);
```

Comment: Hey I had to import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType under "EntityType". No errors, but the .getTypeId()); says that it is deprecated ( with a line slashed through .getTypeId()); ). Is that okay for that to happen?

Comment: @TechStudios A method being deprecated is not a problem, it's just the library telling you "Maybe someday this will be replaced, be careful!", but there's no problem, it will work.

Comment: @TechStudios It's deprecated because they don't want you to use numeric IDs/damage values, but in this case it's the only way.  It indicates that you should try to do it another way if possible; but in this case numeric IDs are the only way of doing it.